# How to plot a point on a image when the point's coordinate is outside the range of the image (matlab)

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure

With MATLAB, it is easy to show an image, and then plot a point on the image. For example,

```
figure; imshow(image);
hold on; plot(x,y,'r*');
```

This can usually work if the point is within the image. When the coordinate (x,y) is not in the range of the image, however, it will not work. For example x=-100,y=-200, in this case, when we use the above codes, the point is not visible anymore. How can I make sure that the point is also visible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `imshow` freezes the axis scale. You need to change the `'XLimMode'` and `'YLimMode'` properties of the axis to `'Auto'` so that it auto-scales.

```
im = randn(300,300);
imshow(im)
hold on
set(gca, 'XLimMode', 'Auto', 'YLimMode', 'Auto')
plot(350,400,'r*')
```

[image]